# RecyclerView ItemTouch Listener gets called everytime

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener, swiperefreshlayout

I have implemented a `RecyclerView` in a layout that has `SwipeRefreshLayout`. I find the `RecyclerView`, set its adapter as well as call the `addOnItemTouchListener()` inside a method. This method is called everytime the `SwipeRefreshLayout` has been refreshed.
Inside the Touch Listener, an `AlertDialog` is called and displayed.
Everytime I refresh in the `SwipeRefreshLayout` it seems to be adding a Touch Listener. What ends up happening is the `AlertDialog` is now displayed more than once depending on how many times you have refreshed.
How can I go about fixing this such that even when it is refreshed the Dialog is only shown once?:

```
private void initRecyclerView() {
    RecyclerView ticketRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_tickets);
    ticketsAdapter = new TicketsAdapter(this);
    ticketRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    ticketRecyclerView.setAdapter(ticketsAdapter);
    ticketRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, ticketRecyclerView, new ClickListener() {
}
}
```

Comment: no need to cast your recyclerview inside the method. and do stuff only whatever u want to do with recyclerview.

Comment: @Manny265 seems no problem with the code. if you still have problem create single instance of `RecyclerView` instead of creating new one everytime. still not solved then we need more description from your side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you refresh, you are adding an `OnItemTouchListener`. This does not replace the previously added listeners; it just adds to them.

To correct this, you will have to either not add additional touch listeners on a refresh or [remove the last one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#removeOnItemTouchListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener)).

> removeOnItemTouchListener
>
> void removeOnItemTouchListener (RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener listener)
>
> Remove an RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener. It will no longer be able to intercept touch events.